# Python list comprehension - generating multiple data

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
import random

M = 4
N = 3


def generisanjevol1(nekalista, m):
    return random.choices(nekalista, k=m)


def generisanjevol2(nekalista, m,n):
    #obj = [[random.choice(nekalista,k=m)] for i in range(N)]]
    obj = [[random.choice(nekalista)] for i in range(n)]
    return obj

    #def poredjenje()


listaslova = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

lista = generisanjevol1(listaslova, M)
lista2 = generisanjevol2(listaslova, M, N)
print(lista)
print(lista2)
```

So above is my try (generisanjevol2(nekalista, m,n)...

What I am trying to do is next:
I want to generate N of arrays and fill them with strings which are generated by random.choice function and they still must be strings from listaslova)
Perhaps  let's say N=3 (N represents numbers of arrays) and M=4 (M represents length of array) I should get something like this (doesn't have to be same data in arrays, because of course they are randomly generated):

```
[A,C,D,E]
([A,C,E,D] [E,C,B,A] [E,D,D,A])
```

But the results which I get are following:

```
[A,D,E,C]
[[B],[D],[E]]
```

P.S If I try the one which is commented I get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your commented line is because you have an extra `]`. And `random.choice` should be `random.choices`.

But you also shouldn't put another list around the call to `random.choice()`. It already returns a list.

```
def generisanjevol2(nekalista, m,n):
    obj = [random.choices(nekalista,k=m) for i in range(n)]
    return obj
```

Comment: In commented line I get error with random.choice(nekalista, k=m)... It says following:
`TypeError: choice() got an unexpected keyword argument 'k' `

Comment: It should be `random.choices`, just like in `generisanjevol1`

Comment: Yes, but then how can I get expected output ? 
I need N lists generated, while in `generisanjevol1`  I just needed 1 list ?

Comment: By calling `random.choices()` in `generisanjevol2`, like I showed in the answer.

Comment: Did you see that I edited the answer after you posted your comment?

Comment: I just have one confusion now, is there anyway that I can compare generated list ?
I want to print out 2 most similar lists from generated ones? 
I can't really get picture of that in my head, how could I just compare them ?

Comment: Write a function that compares the lists and returns a score of how similar they are. Then you can use `sorted(zip(lista2, lista2), key=lambda pair: yourFunction(*pair))`.

Comment: In function which will use for comparing, how can I exactly access lista2 (assuming that I will pass that list as argument in function?)

Comment: Sorry, what I wrote was wrong. You need to make a cross product between `lista2` and itself. You can use `itertools.product(lista2, lista2)`. Then the function receive a pair of sublists as the two arguments.

Comment: Are you sure that it's going to work, since it will make **a pair** of sublists, remember that I can have 2, 3 or more lists generated? 
I don't really understand what `itertools.product(lista2, lista2)` will do? 
If there's going to be 
`[A,B,C,E], [E,C,D,A], [E,E,A,C]` How should I compare these three ? 
 Can you give me one example of if statment ?

Comment: If you have a list like `[1, 2, 3]`, itertools.product will return a new sequence `[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]`. So you get all the pairs of sublists as arguments. Then you compare them and generate a score of how similar they are, and use that to sort them all. The function should also give a bad score if the two lists are the same list, since they'll obviously be most similar.

Comment: I don't think we are on the same pagee here...
So, I understood that I can access lists2[0] and if I do `print(lista2[0])` it's going to print out the first list that I generated in `generisanjevol2`  but how can I compare elements of `lista2[0]` with `lista2[1]` ...  

I think that what you wrote to me is that `itertools.product(lista2, lista2)` is just going to give me permutations and nothing else... And then there's 0 logic behind it since I will compare permutations and NOT each element from lists of lista2

Comment: `itertools.product(lista2, lista2)` will return all the pairs of sublists, like `lista2[0] and lista2[1], lista2[1] and lista2[2]`, and so on. Then `sorted()` will call the function with those pairs, and it will determine how similar they are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222831/discussion-between-barmar-and-pshyotic).

Answer (score 1):

Like @Barmar said, you indeed have an extra `[]`.
Your function should look:

```
def generisanjevol2(nekalista, m,n):
...:     obj = [random.choices(nekalista, k=m) for i in range(n)]
...:     return obj
```